# Trigonometry: 3D rotation around center point

Tags: math, rotation, trigonometry

Yeah, yeah, I checked out the suggested questions/answers that were given to me but most involved quaternions, or had symbols in them that I don't even HAVE on my keyboard.

I failed at high school trig, and while I understand the basic concepts of sin and cos in 2D space, I'm at a loss when throwing in a third plane to deal with.

Basically, I have these things:  centerpoint, distance, and angles for each of the three axes.  Given that information, I want to calculate the point that is -distance- away from the center point, at the specified angles.

I'm not sure I'm explaining this correctly.  My intent is to get what amounts to electrons orbiting around a nucleus, if anyone happens to know how to do that.  I am working with Java, JRE 6, if there are any utility classes in there that can help.

I don't want just an answer, but also the how and why of the answer.  If I'm going to learn something, i want to learn ABOUT it as well.  I am not afraid to take a lesson in trigonometry, or how quaternions work, etc.  I'm not looking for an entire course on the answer, but at least some basic understanding would be cool.

Answer (score 0):

If you did this in 2D, you would have a point on a plane with certain x and y coordinates. The distance from the origin would be `sqrt(x^2+y^2)`, and the angle `atan(y/2)`.

If you were given angle `phi` and distance `r` you would compute `x= r*cos(phi); y=r*sin(phi);`

To do this in three dimensions you need two angles - angle in XY plane and angle relative to Z axis. Calling these phi and theta, you compute coordinates as

```
X = r*cos(phi)*sin(theta);
Y = r*sin(phi)*sin(theta);
Z = r*cos(theta);
```

When I have a chance I will make a sketch to show how that works.